# How to zoom in and move a map of multiple squares?

Tags: java, processing

I have 10x10 sqares that are forming a map. The variable zoom, xPos and yPos are defining how deep I am scolling in the map and the position of the camera.
Each tile has a x and y - coordinate (0-9).
How can I display this map?
I've tried to do this:

rect(x*zoom+xPos, y*zoom+xPos, zoom, zoom); //the function rect makes a rectangle with the center at the first 2 inputs)
The problem is that I'm always zooming in the upper left corner;

I've also tried this:

rect((x-5.5)*zoom+xPos, (y-5.5)*zoom+yPos);

but this zooms always in the center in the map while I want it to zoom in the center of the screen.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I really suggest sitting down with some graph paper and a pencil. Draw out a bunch of example grids with their coordinates and sizes. Then draw out what they look like at different zoom level until you notice a pattern. If you can't get that pattern to work, please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll go from there.

Also note that Processing has a `scale()` function that might come in handy. More info is available in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/scale_.html).

Comment: first I have used the scale() and translate() function in my code but I thought I would put the whole code in the rect() function so that everyone can understand. Guess I have to find it out by myself now. Thanks

Comment: @BertBartan I'm not sure what you mean by putting the whole code in the `rect()` function?

Comment: The only thing that scale() does is multipying each input of functions like rect() with a number. By the way I found out how to do it. I am doing something like this now:

Comment: xPos = round( width/2-z*(nrX-x));
yPos = round(height/2-z*(nrY-y));

Comment: Thanks for all and sry for my bad English